# C++11 thread_local in gcc - alternatives

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, g++, c++11

As I can see at: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html thread_local keyword is unfortunately unsupported in gcc yet.

Are there any alternatives for that? I don't want to use boost library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gcc compiler has a storage class `__thread` that might be close enough.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html

Comment: I tried. Unsuccessfully. Simple: 
__thread int a; 
Produces an error: 
error: storage class specified for 'a'

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y1Fsqnat

Everything is fine if I add static keyword. But then, all objects of class, which belongs to the same thread, will share this variable between them.

Comment: But this is the definition of thread local storage! It cannot be specific to an object (use fields for that)! And an object don't belong to a particular thread, unless you allocate it on stack by making it a local variable!

Comment: @Basile But even then you _could_ pass a reference or pointer to the object to another thread. (Doesn't make it a good idea normally, but I'd be willing to bet that someone has a sane use for it.)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this GCC documentation page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html#Thread_002dLocal), you should try to use `__thread` as a qualifier (like `volatile` or `const` are) for your thread local storage.

Answer (score 4):

[GCC 4.8.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html) includes support for the [`thread_local` storage class](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2659.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example usage of the `__thread` compiler extension (didn't see one above). It is used to create a singleton for each thread called ServiceLocator.

So this is the (abbreviated) header. Here I have the thread local variable as a member of the class.

```
class ServiceLocator :  public ImmutableServiceLocator {
private:
    static __thread ServiceLocator* locator;
public:
    void ServiceLocator::setAsServiceLocator();
    ImmutableServiceLocator& ServiceLocator::getServiceLocator();
};
```

Then you have to put a declaration of the thread local variable in your implementation or else your linker gets confused (I don't know why, sorry), and you can treat the thread local variable just like a static one:

```
__thread ServiceLocator* ServiceLocator::locator;


void ServiceLocator::setAsServiceLocator() {
    locator = this;
}

ImmutableServiceLocator& ServiceLocator::getServiceLocator() {
    return *locator;
}
```